# SQL Query - Along the lines of a pivot table

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have a mock up of a sql query that will represent a real sql query.

```
Create table #tmp
(
    Atype varchar(10),
    Btype varchar(10)
)

insert into #tmp values ('a','x')
insert into #tmp values ('b','x')
insert into #tmp values ('a','y')
insert into #tmp values ('a','y')
insert into #tmp values ('b','z')
insert into #tmp values ('b','y')

select atype, btype,count(*) as count
from #tmp
group by atype, btype
order by atype

drop table #tmp
```

This will give me the result of:

```
atype btype count
-----------------
a     x     1
a     y     2
b     x     1
b     y     1
b     z     1
```

What i am looking for after this is to be able to create a report that basically looks like:

```
atype|x| y| z
-------------
a    |1| 2| 0
b    |1| 1| 1
```

I am sure you can do this using come crazy t-sql code but i am struggeling to get it right.

EDIT:

I agree that you can use the TSQL PIVOT command but what happens when Btype is variable.  Meaning that i dont know how many types there will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  atype, 
  SUM(CASE btype WHEN 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS x,
  SUM(CASE btype WHEN 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y,
  SUM(CASE btype WHEN 'z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z
FROM
  #tmp
group by 
  atype
order by 
  atype
```

Comment: +1 for nice and compact code. Note to self: when using comparison operators, put the WHEN immediately after the CASE, such as:   ColA       , SUM(CASE WHEN Days <= 0 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0]
, SUM(CASE WHEN Days = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1]

Comment: @mg1075 The two forms of writing a `WHEN` are different from each other: The `CASE x WHEN 1 THEN foo WHEN 2 THEN bar END` resembles a `switch` statement, it does not accept expressions. Whereas `CASE WHEN x=1 THEN foo WHEN x=2 THEN bar END` resembles `if-else if` and expects expressions. Use the appropriate form for each case.

Answer (score 1):

`@Tomalak`'s answer is nice, but there's nothing crazy about it, just plain old `SQL`.

Here's the really crazy `T-SQL` code you asked for, in case you were interested:

```
SELECT  atype, [x], [y], [z]
FROM    (
        SELECT  atype, btype
        FROM    #tmp
        ) t
PIVOT
        (
        COUNT(btype)
        FOR btype IN ([x], [y], [z])
        ) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a direct pivot is supported only by SQL Server 2005 , as shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191230182030/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/lorint/archive/2006/08/04/87166.aspx)

Here is how it can be done with Oracle - http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/examples/pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

See this for a stored procedure for MySQL that produces a cross-tabulation:

http://www.futhark.ch/mysql/106.html